# Can Aeschynomene aspera be used in constructed wetland for filtering grey water?

Tags: greywater

**Updated the question to be more specific, after the first answer.**

Can [Aeschynomene aspera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeschynomene_aspera) be used in constructed wetland for filtering grey water in Tropical Climate, especially in Eastern India (West Bengal)?

[Aeschynomene aspera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeschynomene_aspera) grows in watery area but I have not seen their mention in grey water filtration, possibly due to the the sparse documentation regarding this topic based on West Bengal, India geography.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly as it's an aquatic plant. However it's deemed a weed to rice growers. In constructed wetlands, best to plant what existed in the wetlands that lived in that region.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have updated the question to be more specific.